# Visual Studio WinForm C++ Threads unsafe

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

In the following code (compiled with /clr) which is deliberately writing to the Console, the threads are either freezing the GUI or not giving any results.

Any ideas are welcome.
Also in particular the line  this->Invoke(d, gcnew array { AA, BB });
is only taking 2 arguments and the code compiles. If I try 3 arguments as the delegate requires, the code doesn't compile. Any ideas why?

Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
#using <System.Drawing.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

#define                 NN  1000000
unsigned long long      AA = 0;
unsigned long long      BB = 99999999999999999ull;
unsigned long long      PP[NN];

bool IsPrime(unsigned long long number)
{
    if (number == 2 || number == 3)
        return true;

    if (number % 2 == 0 || number % 3 == 0)
        return false;

    int divisor = 6;
    while (divisor * divisor - 2 * divisor + 1 <= number)
   {
        if (number % (divisor - 1) == 0)
            return false;

        if (number % (divisor + 1) == 0)
           return false;

        divisor += 6;
    }
    return true;
}

void NextPrime(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long * prime)
{
    while (!IsPrime(++a))
    {
    }

    * prime = a;
}

void FindAllPrimes(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long * prime)
{
    unsigned long long k, n;
    n = 0;
    for (k = a; k < b; k++)
    {
        if (IsPrime(k))
        {
            prime[n] = k;
            n++;
            if (n >= 1000000)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public ref class Form1 : public Form
{

delegate void Delegate_Call(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long * prime);

    private: void Function_1()
    {
        FindAllPrimes(AA, BB, PP);
    }

    private: void Function_2()
    {
        this->Function_3(AA, BB, PP);
    }

    private: void Function_3(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long * prime)
    {
        if (this->textBox1->InvokeRequired)
        {
            Delegate_Call^ d = gcnew Delegate_Call(this, &Form1::Function_3);

            this->Invoke(d, gcnew array<Object^> { AA, BB });

            int n = rand() % NN;

            this->textBox1->Text = PP[n].ToString();

            for (int n = 0; n < NN; n++)
                std::cout << PP[n] << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            FindAllPrimes(AA, BB, PP);

            int n = rand() % NN;
            this->textBox1->Text = PP[n].ToString();
            for (int n = 0; n < NN; n++)
                std::cout << PP[n] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    private: Thread^ Thread_A;

    private: BackgroundWorker^ backgroundWorker1;
    private: TextBox^ textBox1;
    private: Button^ Button_DoNotKnow;
    private: Button^ Button_UnSafeCall;
    private: Button^ Button_SafeCall;
    private: Button^ Button_BGWorker;

    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^ components;

    public: Form1()
        {
            components = nullptr;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    protected: ~Form1()
        {
            if (components != nullptr)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private: void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this->textBox1 = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox();
            this->Button_DoNotKnow = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button();
            this->Button_UnSafeCall = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button();
            this->Button_SafeCall = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button();
            this->Button_BGWorker = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button();
            this->backgroundWorker1 = gcnew System::ComponentModel::BackgroundWorker();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            //
            // textBox1
            //
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(30, 30);
            this->textBox1->Name = "textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(310, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;               
            //
            // Button_DoNotKnow
            //
            this->Button_DoNotKnow->Location = System::Drawing::Point(20, 70);
            this->Button_DoNotKnow->Name = "Button_DoNotKnow";
            this->Button_DoNotKnow->TabIndex = 1;
            this->Button_DoNotKnow->Text = "DoNotKnow";
            this->Button_DoNotKnow->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Button_DoNotKnow_Click);
            //
            // Button_UnSafeCall
            //
            this->Button_UnSafeCall->Location = System::Drawing::Point(100, 70);
            this->Button_UnSafeCall->Name = "Button_UnSafeCall";
            this->Button_UnSafeCall->TabIndex = 2;
            this->Button_UnSafeCall->Text = "Unsafe Call";
            this->Button_UnSafeCall->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Button_UnSafeCall_Click);
            //
            // Button_SafeCall
            //
            this->Button_SafeCall->Location = System::Drawing::Point(180, 70);
            this->Button_SafeCall->Name = "Button_SafeCall";
            this->Button_SafeCall->TabIndex = 3;
            this->Button_SafeCall->Text = "Safe Call";
            this->Button_SafeCall->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Button_SafeCall_Click);
            //
            // Button_BGWorker
            //
            this->Button_BGWorker->Location = System::Drawing::Point(260, 70);
            this->Button_BGWorker->Name = "Button_BGWorker";
            this->Button_BGWorker->TabIndex = 4;
            this->Button_BGWorker->Text = "Safe BW Call";
            this->Button_BGWorker->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::Button_BGWorker_Click);
            //
            // backgroundWorker1
            //
            this->backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerCompleted += gcnew System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler( this, &Form1::backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            //
            // Form1
            //
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(380, 180);
            this->Controls->Add(this->Button_BGWorker);
            this->Controls->Add(this->Button_SafeCall);
            this->Controls->Add(this->Button_UnSafeCall);
            this->Controls->Add(this->Button_DoNotKnow);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Name = "Form1";
            this->Text = "Form1";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();
    }

    private: void Button_DoNotKnow_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
        FindAllPrimes(AA, BB, PP);

        for (int n = 0; n < NN; n++)
            std::cout << PP[n] << std::endl;
    }

    private: void Button_UnSafeCall_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
        this->Thread_A = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::Function_1));

        this->Thread_A->Start();
    }

    private: void Button_SafeCall_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
        this->Thread_A = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &Form1::Function_2));

        this->Thread_A->Start();
    }

    private: void Button_BGWorker_Click(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
    {
        this->backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private: void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(Object^ sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^ e)
    {
        FindAllPrimes(AA, BB, PP);

        for (int n = 0; n < NN; n++)
            std::cout << PP[n] << std::endl;
    }

};
}

[STAThread]
int main()
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::Run(gcnew MyNameSpace::Form1());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the reason why the Form hangs is that you are printing 1 million lines to the console from the UI thread. Try to change the `NN` to lets say 100 and you will see the hang goes away. If you want to keep the `NN` 1 million, than the only option is to move it to non UI thread.

```
for (int n = 0; n < NN; n++)
   std::cout << PP[n] << std::endl;
```

The second problem, related to the invoke is, that the `Invoke` expects array of `System::Object^`. There is no implicit conversion from `unsigned long long*` to `System::Object^`, so we have to convert it to `IntPtr`, which will be converted to `System::Object^`.

```
private: void Function_3(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b, unsigned long long * prime)
{
    if (this->textBox1->InvokeRequired)
    {
        Delegate_Call^ d = gcnew Delegate_Call(this, &Form1::Function_3);

        //this->Invoke(d, gcnew array<Object^> { AA, BB, IntPtr(PP) });

        // btw, you can use it also this way
        this->Invoke(d, AA, BB, IntPtr(PP));

        //int n = rand() % NN;

        // we are still on non UI thread so this will end in CrossThread eception ofcourse
        //this->textBox1->Text = PP[n].ToString();

        //for (int n = 0; n < NN; n++)
        //    std::cout << PP[n] << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        FindAllPrimes(AA, BB, PP);

        int n = rand() % NN;
        this->textBox1->Text = PP[n].ToString();
        for (int n = 0; n < NN; n++)
            std::cout << PP[n] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I want to keep printing the 1 million line.  This is for other requirements in the project.  I tried your changes, the code is printing on the console, but I can not move the GUI. or press any button (later I want to add a button to cancel) Can you please help to make the GUI responsive while is printing to the Console.  Also Can you please write some code how to start a none GUI thread and how move the function call to the non GUI thread. Thank you in advance.